# Fatal error: Cannot declare class , because the name is already in use

Tags: magento2, class

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Vendor\Modelname\ResourceModel\Doccount, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/readyresale/app/code/Vendor\Modelname/Model/ResourceModel/Doccount.php on line 23

**ResourceModel/Doccount.php file**

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Doccount extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init ( 'documentcountable','id' );
    }
}
```

**model/Doccountmodel.php file**

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Doccountmodel extends AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init ( 'Vendor\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Doccount' );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add code for this file?

Answer (score 9):

Replace

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\ResourceModel;
```

With

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel;
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer put me on the right track: My issue was that the namespace was simply wrong, i.e. I had put "Block" twice into the namespace.